# How to correctly parse out elements from a complex string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have data that can be in certain formats that I am having trouble correctly parsing. Originally I was using re.split to separate on periods and conditionally join certain elements, however this created additional issues that I thought could be solved with regex, but I don't know how to format it correctly.

The data can be in the following formats

```py
STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.VARIABLE1.STATICFIELD3/VARIABLE2
STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.VARIABLE1.VARIABLE2.STATICFIELD3/VARIABLE3
STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2..VARIABLE1.STATICFIELD3/VARIABLE2
STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.VARIABLE1/VARIABLE2
STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2..VARIABLE1/VARIABLE2
```

The problem I am having, is that using regex to split based on periods and slashes, means that if the varaible is preceded with a period, it doesn't include the period. I want to be able to have the variable in the form of a string if it has a period in front, for example var = ".VARIABLE1" and at the same time var = "VARIABLE.VARIABLE2". I don't need to store the static fields, I just need to be able to extract the variable fields regardless of whether there is one, two, or one with literal period in front.

I have tried using re.search, but can only obtain the first static field.
I have tried using re.split('.|/',line) but then I run into issues with not being able to parse the variables that have periods in front, like ".car" instead of "car", or I have to manually join the ones with two variables with ['.'.join(x[2:4])], which I don't want to do because of the variability of the total amount of fields.

My desired output for the given examples would be two separate variables holding the variables from the input

```py
x = VARIABLE1 y = VARIABLE2
x = VARIABLE1.VARIABLE2 y = VARIABLE3
x = .VARIABLE1 y = VARIABLE2
x = VARIABLE1 y = VARIABLE2
x = .VARIABLE1 y= VARIABLE2
```

```py
    x = re.split('\/', r)
    numElements = len(x)
    if(x[(numElements - 2)] == "STATICFIELD2"):
        y[x[2]] = 1
        else:
            x[2:4] = ['.'.join(x[2:4])]
        y[x[2]] = 1
```

```py
    x = re.search(r'(\bSTATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.\b+)(\b.STATICFIELD3/\b)',line)
```

Comment: Please provide an example of desired output

Comment: Edited for clarity and desired output

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the STATICFIELD patterns from the string and then do a simple split on slash:

```
import re

def splitXY(s) : return re.sub("(\.?STATICFIELD\d+\.?)","",s).split("/")

x,y = splitXY("STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.VARIABLE1.STATICFIELD3/VARIABLE2")
print(x,y)  # VARIABLE1 VARIABLE2
x,y = splitXY("STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.VARIABLE1.VARIABLE2.STATICFIELD3/VARIABLE3")
print(x,y)  # VARIABLE1.VARIABLE2 VARIABLE3
x,y = splitXY("STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2..VARIABLE1.STATICFIELD3/VARIABLE2")
print(x,y)  # .VARIABLE1 VARIABLE2
x,y = splitXY("STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.VARIABLE1/VARIABLE2")
print(x,y)  # VARIABLE1 VARIABLE2
x,y = splitXY("STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2..VARIABLE1/VARIABLE2")
print(x,y)  # .VARIABLE1 VARIABLE2
```

**[UPDATE]**

If you have some logic that allows you to distinguish names that are STATICFIELDs from names that are VARIABLEs, you could use split and join to parse your strings:

```
def isStatic(name): # this would be whatever logic distinguishes the names
    return name != "" and name.startswith("STATICFIELD")

def splitXY(s) :
    x,y = s.split("/")
    x =  ".".join(name for name in x.split(".") if not isStatic(name))
    return x,y

x,y = splitXY("STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.VARIABLE1.STATICFIELD3/VARIABLE2")
print(x,y)  # VARIABLE1 VARIABLE2
x,y = splitXY("STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.VARIABLE1.VARIABLE2.STATICFIELD3/VARIABLE3")
print(x,y)  # VARIABLE1.VARIABLE2 VARIABLE3
x,y = splitXY("STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2..VARIABLE1.STATICFIELD3/VARIABLE2")
print(x,y)  # .VARIABLE1 VARIABLE2
x,y = splitXY("STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.VARIABLE1/VARIABLE2")
print(x,y)  # VARIABLE1 VARIABLE2
x,y = splitXY("STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2..VARIABLE1/VARIABLE2")
print(x,y)  # .VARIABLE1 VARIABLE2
```

*Make sure that `isStatic()` responds with `False` for empty names*

Comment: I see what you're trying to do, but how would I account for and define the various static fields in the regex, including the case where the a static field doesn't exist? Thanks!

Comment: If you don't have a pattern to distinguish STATICFIELDs from VARIABLEs, there will be no way to isolate the names and A.B.C could be interpreted as STATICFIELD1.VARIABLE1.STATICFIELD2 or STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.VARIABLE1.  The parsing would have no way of knowing.   Perhaps there is a pattern or list of values that you could provide in your question to disambiguate these situations.

Answer (score 0):

So, for the question as asked I suspect you were dinged because someone thinks you're being literal when you say `VARIABLE` vs `STATICFIELD`, because if you are you, likely could have considered switching to using findall.

If that's what you needed the below should work and then you can process it

**Edit: Option 1**

```
>>> string = '''STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.VARIABLE1.STATICFIELD3/VARIABLE2
STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.VARIABLE1.VARIABLE2.STATICFIELD3/VARIABLE3
STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2..VARIABLE1.STATICFIELD3/VARIABLE2
STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.VARIABLE1/VARIABLE2
STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2..VARIABLE1/VARIABLE2'''



>>> def isolate_variables(string):
        import re
        result = []
        for line in string.split('\n'):
            x,y = re.findall('(?i)(?:(?<=\s|\.|\/)|(?<=^))(VARIABLE[\d]+?[\.]+(?:VARIABLE[\d]*)+|(?:(?<=\s|\.|\/)|(?<=^))[\.]*VARIABLE[\d]+?)(?=[\.\/\n\ ]|$)', line)
            result.append((x,y))
        print(result)
        return result



>>> isolate_variables(string)



#OUTPUT
[('VARIABLE1', 'VARIABLE2'), ('VARIABLE1.VARIABLE2', 'VARIABLE3'), ('.VARIABLE1', 'VARIABLE2'), ('VARIABLE1', 'VARIABLE2'), ('.VARIABLE1', 'VARIABLE2')]
```

.

**Option 2 - You'd just need to process after**

```
>>> import re


>>> string = '''STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.VARIABLE1.STATICFIELD3/VARIABLE2
STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.VARIABLE1.VARIABLE2.STATICFIELD3/VARIABLE3
STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2..VARIABLE1.STATICFIELD3/VARIABLE2
STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2.VARIABLE1/VARIABLE2
STATICFIELD1.STATICFIELD2..VARIABLE1/VARIABLE2'''


>>> re.findall('(?i)(?:(?<=\s|\.|\/)|(?<=^))(VARIABLE[\d]+?[\.]+(?:VARIABLE[\d]*)+|(?:(?<=\s|\.|\/)|(?<=^))[\.]*VARIABLE[\d]+?)(?=[\.\/\n\ ]|$)', string)



#OUTPUT
['VARIABLE1', 'VARIABLE2', 'VARIABLE1.VARIABLE2', 'VARIABLE3', '.VARIABLE1', 'VARIABLE2', 'VARIABLE1', 'VARIABLE2', '.VARIABLE1', 'VARIABLE2']
```